# how to get custom output from grep command

Tags: grep

So using `exim` and `sed` commands I'm getting the results as below

```
10 /home/user1
20 /home/user2/public_html
30 /home/user3
40 /home/user4/public_html
50 /home/user5
60 /home/user6/public_html
```

This shows how many mails has been send from user. 
How can I get the result in descending order and get the username only?

i.e., from above result I want to `grep user6` and then run `/scripts/suspendacct user6`

Answer (score 1):

With awk and sort:

```
awk -F '[/ ]' '{print $1,$4}' file | sort -n -r
```

Output:

```
60 user6
50 user5
40 user4
30 user3
20 user2
10 user1
```

Comment: I got it.. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Or use `cut` to get the fields you want and pipe to `sort`:

```
$ cut --output-delimiter="" -d / -f 1,3 file | sort -r
60 user6
50 user5
40 user4
30 user3
20 user2
10 user1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to grep multiline after your query string, you can use it

```
grep -A 3 "your query string" your_file
```

`3` is the line number you want to see after your condition.

Line number after your query: `-A NUM, --after-context=NUM`

Line number before your query: `-B NUM, --before-context=NUM`